# Howto reference a LESS file without actually importing/overriding variables

Tags: scope, less, phpstorm

I am trying to reuse some desktop modules for a mobile version of my webpage. All module.less references `variables.less` - mostly for the IDE (PhpStorm), but also for having the dependencies at a glance, which I really like.

Up to now I thought this LESS rule is really referencing - actually it is not like that. The files get really included (once) but without outputting (see LESS docs). As a result my mobile variables get overridden.

```
├ desktop/
│  ├ modules/
│  │  └ foobar.less
│  │      > @import (reference) "../variables.less"
│  ├ main.less
│  │   > @import "variables.less"
│  │   > @import "modules.less"
│  ├ modules.less
│  │   > @import "modules/foobar.less"
│  └ variables.less
│      > @bundle: 'desktop'
│
└ mobile/  
   ├ main.less
   │   > @import "variables.less"
   │   > @import "modules.less"
   ├ modules.less
   │   > @import "../desktop/modules/foobar.less"
   └ variables.less
       > @bundle: 'mobile'
```

After compiling the mobile `mobile/main.less` the result is `@bundle` equals `'desktop'`.

Is there a possibility to *only* "reference" the variables.less? Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Does you `variables.less` contain anything *but* variables? If not you're probably totally misunderstand and thus misuse `(reference)`. It's really nothing but ["without adding the imported *styles* to the compiled output"](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference). When it comes to *variables* (not CSS *styles*) what really matters is the ["Lazy-Evaluation"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading), thus for your particular example this ultimately reduces to the order you import your different `variables.less` files in and has nothing to do with `(reference)`.

Comment: For more details on Less variable lifetime, scope and overriding/overwriting stuff see for example: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442#issuecomment-73841148.

Comment: @seven-phases-max yes, as mentioned I misunderstood the actual behavior of `reference`. And yes my file contains only variables - actually the same in both packages, but with different values in some places. So actually inheritance would be nice. Thanks for that Github link. The discussion is very interesting, especially using `& {@import "package";}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with a very easy solution:

Simply import `desktop/variables.less` at the beginning of `mobile/variables.less`. This works because the default LESS behavior is *import once*. Since it is already imported before all modules, the desktop module's `@import` rule won't cause (re-)importing - therefore won't overwrite any variables:

```
├ desktop/
│  ├ modules/
│  │  └ foobar.less
│  │      > @import (reference) "../variables.less"
│  ├ main.less
│  │   > @import "variables.less"
│  │   > @import "modules.less"
│  ├ modules.less
│  │   > @import "modules/foobar.less"
│  └ variables.less
│      > @bundle: 'desktop'
│
└ mobile/  
   ├ main.less
   │   > @import "variables.less"
   │   > @import "modules.less"
   ├ modules.less
   │   > @import "../desktop/modules/foobar.less"
   └ variables.less
       > @import (reference) "../desktop/variables.less"
       > @bundle: 'mobile'
```